# Communities / Partner Portal Issue. No Available Community error message

Tags: partner-portal, partner-communities, portal

I have set up communities in my organisation. When I try and log into the community, by clicking on the 'Manager External User' button on a contact I receive an error stating 'No available community'. Can anyone advise? I believe this may be something to do with assigning the profile but I cannot see where I can do this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to:
Setup -> Customize Communities -> Manage Communities

Then press the 'Edit' link left of the Community

Then add the profile/permission set to the Members using the 'Members' button at the top left of the menu.